# Access attributes of a SVG node

Tags: javascript, svg, visio, siblings

I have a SVG file I'm displaying and from which I want to get informations of when I click on specific element.

Here is the part of the SVG :

```
        <g id="group327-2702" transform="translate(1539.96,-1043.15)" v:mID="327" v:groupContext="group">
        <v:custProps>
            <v:cp v:nameU="idApplication" v:lbl="idApplication" v:type="0" v:sortKey="1" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(143)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="labelFR" v:lbl="labelFR" v:type="0" v:sortKey="3" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(Carnet d&#39;ordres)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="labelEN" v:lbl="labelEN" v:type="0" v:sortKey="4" v:langID="1036"
                    v:val="VT4(Order Management System )"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="type" v:lbl="Type" v:type="0" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(Business)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="appLevel" v:lbl="appLevel" v:type="0" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(3)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="name" v:lbl="name" v:type="0" v:sortKey="2" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(MCE Trading)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="External" v:lbl="External" v:type="0" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(FALSE)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="_VisDM_type" v:lbl="type" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(Business)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="_VisDM_status" v:lbl="status" v:type="2" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT0(1):26"/>
        </v:custProps>
        <v:userDefs>
            <v:ud v:nameU="msvStructureType" v:prompt="" v:val="VT4(Container)"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="msvSDContainerMargin" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(0.078740157480315):24"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="Label" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(2):26"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="ShapeVersion" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(1):26"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="LightColorText" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(0):5"/>
        </v:userDefs>
        <title>Module.52.327</title>
        <g id="shape328-2703" v:mID="328" v:groupContext="shape">
            <title>Feuille.328</title>
            <v:userDefs>
                <v:ud v:nameU="visVersion" v:val="VT0(14):26"/>
            </v:userDefs>
            <rect x="0" y="1652.6" width="93.5433" height="31.1811" rx="2.83465" ry="2.83465" class="st72"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape327-2705" v:mID="327" v:groupContext="groupContent">
            <v:textBlock v:margins="rect(4,4,4,4)" v:tabSpace="42.5197"/>
            <v:textRect cx="46.7717" cy="1668.19" width="93.55" height="31.1811"/>
            <text x="28.54" y="1661.89" class="st73" v:langID="1036"><v:paragraph v:horizAlign="1"/><v:tabList/>MCE Trading<v:newlineChar/><v:newlineChar/><tspan
                        x="7.63" dy="2.4em" class="st5">Order Management System </tspan> </text>            </g>
    </g>
```

I need to access the attributes of the first child of my node `<v:custProps>` :

`<v:cp v:nameU="idApplication" v:lbl="idApplication" v:type="0" v:sortKey="1" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(143)"/>`

The weird thing is that there is empty text sibling between each node :
For example, if I do that :

```
var msg = "";
    msg += "target nodeName, width x height : " + evt.target.nodeName + ", " + evt.target.getAttributeNodeNS(null, 'width').nodeValue + " x " + evt.target.getAttributeNodeNS(null, 'height').nodeValue + "\n\n";

    msg += "parent nodeName, id : " + evt.target.parentNode.nodeName + ", " + evt.target.parentNode.id + "\n\n";

    msg += "parent previousSibling nodeName : " + evt.target.parentNode.previousSibling.nodeName + "\n\n";

    msg += "parent 2 previousSibling nodeName : " + evt.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.nodeName + "\n\n";

    msg += "parent 3 previousSibling nodeName : " + evt.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.nodeName + "\n\n";

    msg += "parent 4 previousSibling nodeName : " + evt.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.nodeName + "\n\n";

    msg += "parent 5 previousSibling nodeName : " + evt.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.nodeName + "\n\n";

    msg += "parent 6 previousSibling nodeName : " + evt.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.nodeName + "\n\n";

    msg += "parent 6 previousSibling firstChild nodeName : " + evt.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.firstChild.nodeName + "\n\n";

    msg += "parent 6 previousSibling firstChild nextSibling nodeName : " + evt.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.firstChild.nextSibling.nodeName + "\n\n";

alert(msg);
```

The result is :

> target nodeName, width x height : rect, 93.5433 x 31.1811
>
> parent nodeName, id : g, shape328-2703
>
> parent previousSibling nodeName : #text
>
> parent 2 previousSibling nodeName : title
>
> parent 3 previousSibling nodeName : #text
>
> parent 4 previousSibling nodeName : v:userDefs
>
> parent 5 previousSibling nodeName : #text
>
> parent 6 previousSibling nodeName : v:custProps
>
> parent 6 previousSibling firstChild nodeName : #text
>
> parent 6 previousSibling firstChild nextSibling nodeName : v:cp

So now I accessed (in a strange way) my node `<v:cp v:nameU="idApplication" v:lbl="idApplication" v:type="0" v:sortKey="1" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(143)"/>`, I'm trying to get the attributes.

For example : 
`msg += "parent 6 previousSibling firstChild nextSibling v:nameU : " + evt.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.firstChild.nextSibling.getAttributeNS(null, 'v:nameU') + "\n\n";`

But this is not working. I tried to add an id to the line, and I can get the id attribute. But for the existing attributes, it is not working.

So, why is there text sibling between each node that doesnt appear in the svg structure ?

Why can't I access the attributes I'm trying to get ? Is it because they come from Visio (v:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to get the attribute I wanted doing as follows, thanks Kaiido for your help :

```
var element = evt.target.parentNode;
    while (element) {
        if (element.children.length > 0) {
            var efc = element.firstElementChild;
            if (efc.hasAttribute("v:nameU")) {
                if (efc.getAttribute("v:nameU") == "idApplication") {
                    element.style.cursor = "help";
                    var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
                    var appId = efc.getAttribute("v:val").match(regExp);
                    alert("id : " + appId[1]);
                    break;
                }
                else
                    element = element.previousElementSibling;
            }
            else
                element = element.previousElementSibling;
        }
        else
            element = element.previousElementSibling;
    }
}
```

But this line `element.style.cursor = "help";` is not working, the cursor icon stays the same over an element matching an idApplication.

The thing to know is my svg is in a different file included into my html through a `<object>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) and [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling).

TextNodes are nodes, and spaces between tags in your doc might be TextNodes.

```js
var g=document.querySelector('#group327-2702');
var cpElement = g.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling;
var r = cpElement.getAttributeNS(null, "v:nameu")+' '+
    cpElement.getAttributeNS(null, "v:lbl")+' '+
    cpElement.getAttributeNS(null, "v:type")+' '+
    cpElement.getAttributeNS(null, "v:sortkey")+' '+
    cpElement.getAttributeNS(null, "v:langid")+' '+
    cpElement.getAttributeNS(null, "v:val");

document.querySelector('p').textContent= r;
```

```html
<svg><g id="group327-2702" transform="translate(1539.96,-1043.15)" v:mID="327" v:groupContext="group"><v:custProps>
            <v:cp v:nameU="idApplication" v:lbl="idApplication" v:type="0" v:sortKey="1" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(143)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="labelFR" v:lbl="labelFR" v:type="0" v:sortKey="3" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(Carnet d&#39;ordres)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="labelEN" v:lbl="labelEN" v:type="0" v:sortKey="4" v:langID="1036"
                    v:val="VT4(Order Management System )"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="type" v:lbl="Type" v:type="0" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(Business)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="appLevel" v:lbl="appLevel" v:type="0" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(3)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="name" v:lbl="name" v:type="0" v:sortKey="2" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(MCE Trading)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="External" v:lbl="External" v:type="0" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(FALSE)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="_VisDM_type" v:lbl="type" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT4(Business)"/>
            <v:cp v:nameU="_VisDM_status" v:lbl="status" v:type="2" v:langID="1036" v:val="VT0(1):26"/>
        </v:custProps>
        <v:userDefs>
            <v:ud v:nameU="msvStructureType" v:prompt="" v:val="VT4(Container)"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="msvSDContainerMargin" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(0.078740157480315):24"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="Label" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(2):26"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="ShapeVersion" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(1):26"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="LightColorText" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(0):5"/>
        </v:userDefs>
        <title>Module.52.327</title>
        <g id="shape328-2703" v:mID="328" v:groupContext="shape">
            <title>Feuille.328</title>
            <v:userDefs>
                <v:ud v:nameU="visVersion" v:val="VT0(14):26"/>
            </v:userDefs>
            <rect x="0" y="1652.6" width="93.5433" height="31.1811" rx="2.83465" ry="2.83465" class="st72"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape327-2705" v:mID="327" v:groupContext="groupContent">
            <v:textBlock v:margins="rect(4,4,4,4)" v:tabSpace="42.5197"/>
            <v:textRect cx="46.7717" cy="1668.19" width="93.55" height="31.1811"/>
            <text x="28.54" y="1661.89" class="st73" v:langID="1036"><v:paragraph v:horizAlign="1"/><v:tabList/>MCE Trading<v:newlineChar/><v:newlineChar/><tspan
                        x="7.63" dy="2.4em" class="st5">Order Management System </tspan> </text>            </g>
    </g></svg>

<p id="log"></p>
```

Also, thing I discovered thanks to your problem, note that you have to lowercase the attributes you're looking with `getAttributeNS()`

Comment: Hey, thanks ! That's what I assumed about the text node. However, lowercase or not, `getAttributeNS()` doesn't work. But `getAttribute` does (with the same case). So i managed to make it work now. I will post the answer. However I don't get why for my `<title>`  element, `hasChildNodes()` returns true since my `<title>` is empty and `firstElementChild` is null . I'm guessing, this is the empty text node. I would need a `hasChildElements` method to do it without this particular case i handle manuelly.

Comment: @Ellone, instead of `hasChildNodes()`, you could check for the length of `element.chidren` if it is > 0, then your element has child elements. And about getAttribute, I sincerely don't understand, HTML attributes are case insensitive while XML are... So in my understanding, it should be the inverse…

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Right now I'm trying to change the cursor icon when it is over an element that match an idApplication, so in the condition I tried to add : 
`if (efc.getAttribute("v:nameU") == "idApplication") {
                            efc.style.cursor = "help";
...`
But I'm guessing I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes you should apply the style to the hovered `element`, not your `efc`

Comment: This is not working neither. But actually I think it's because my SVG is in a different file. I'm including it into my html using a `<object>` so I'm not sure how to achieve this.